# Download dSYM fails "Missing App Version"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-organizer, dsym

When I try to download the dSYM from the organizer, it gives me this error :

Missing App Version
An app record for “co.**” was found but a matching version for “1.0.3” build “10” was not.

I have enabled Bitcode. It's a swift app with Swift and Objective-C pods. Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)

When I right click on the archive and look at it's package contents in Finder, I see a dSYMs folder. I zipped it and uplaoded it to Crashlytics, but it still shows dSYMs missing for all my builds. It even has App.dsym with some dsyms with UUIDs and others for my pods.

Is this an XCode bug?

I see somene has posted a similar question for tvOS on the apple developer forum but there are no answers there. I am not allowed to ask a question there for some reason :p

I haven't added a build to iTunesConnect yet, is that necessary to download dSYMs? Where does XCode download the dSYM from? Could it have something to do with the fact that my bundleId is of the form co.someString and not co.someString.someOtherString? I guess not, I'm just looking for anything.

Is disabling bitcode the only way to be able to get the dSYM for me?

Comment: Have you found the answer? I faced with the same problem.

Comment: I still haven't found the answer. I'm thinking of moving to Firebase analytics and crash reporting :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your **dSYM file doesn't match the application binary**, even if app version number and build number would be correct. Every time you build (archive) app, you get new and different dSYM file, too.

You cannot use just any dSYM file from any archived project, even if you made no code changes between archives. You must get the exactly correct archive and dSYM from within it.

Here's related [info from HockeyApp](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems), similar service to Crashlytics. Even if they are diff services, symbolicating crash reports is similar problem.

Comment: What might cause my dSYM not matching the binary? How can I fix that?

Comment: The top paragraph of the linked article explains that. Every time you build your app the binary will get a new UUID and a new dSYM is created for that exact binary. For symbolication you need the exact corresponding files. So if you upload a dSYM, then build again and get a crash for that but did not upload the newly created symbol, symbolication will not work.

Comment: So when Crashlytics tries to report a crash for me, even when I disable bitcode, it results in an error 422 which means it could not find the dSYM. Any idea why this could be happening. I've tried to look for dSYMs with correct UUIDs in every way I knew, ls grep, find, spotlight, but they're just not there.