# dSYM file doesn't match the application binary

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.2, dsym

I have transferred my app between two companies.

I am now using xcode 7.2.1 (just upgraded from 7.2 and on a new mac).

Built the app using new provision, certs etc. Everything works including push. However, I now get the following dSym error:

```
Download dSYM fails “Missing App Version”
```

I looked closely at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225755/download-dsym-fails-missing-app-version) answer but I just do not understand what is going on.

I followed the answer to [this](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems) link but I am still not clear what to do about this.

I navigated to the archive, copied the app and dsym folders to another directory (just in case) and:

- I ran this command:

  **dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app/MyApp**
- Followed by:

  **dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app.dSYM**

The 'UUID' outcome was identical:
UUID: 4627E331-25CA-3C0E-9B6E-628F47860443 (armv7) MyApp.app/MyApp
UUID: B88F67EC-B6BF-347B-A2E0-CE83F1DFB31C (arm64) MyApp.app/MyApp

UUID: 4627E331-25CA-3C0E-9B6E-628F47860443 (armv7) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp
UUID: B88F67EC-B6BF-347B-A2E0-CE83F1DFB31C (arm64) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp

After I uploaded the archive to itunes connect (was processed successfully), I clicked on 'Download dSym'. The message I got this time was:
 Up To Date
 There are no dSYMs available for download.

What am I missing? Is the issue somewhere else? Is it just xcode? Close and reopen?

Forgot to mention that I was also able to download the dSym from itunes...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353101/swift-compatibility-between-versions-for-a-library/33408323#33408323

Comment: ^ that seems unrelated.